# Precut fruit is kosher but not lemon?

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, travel, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

I'm confused by what I'm reading [here](http://dinonline.org/2012/09/14/keeping-kosher-when-traveling-and-in-a-non-kosher-environment/):

> 1. **Fresh fruits and vegetables grown in chutz la’aretz are kosher whether bought whole or cut. Therefore, you may purchase a fresh fruit
>      salad in any restaurant** (if there is no dressing on it). If the
>      restaurant serves kosher and non-kosher items, you may enter it to
>      eat. If none of the food served is kosher, you may only be seated if
>      there are no Jews around to see or if you are not recognizable as
>      Jewish. Although you couldn’t eat there, you might want to enter for a
>      meeting with someone and just drink water.
> 2. You may drink cold drinks such as soda and beer in the glasses provided in a non-kosher restaurant. If the drink is normally served
>      with a slice of lemon, **ask them to hold the lemon. Since the lemon was
>      cut with a treif knife, the lemon is treif and should not be put into
>      tea or a cold beverage.** If it was wedged on the glass, you should
>      remove the lemon and may drink the beverage. Any lemon that remains in
>      the drink is negligible and does not pose a problem. If the lemon was
>      squeezed into the drink, order another drink without the lemon and
>      offer the first drink to a gentile you know or have it returned to the
>      kitchen.

Why does this document apparently state that one doesn't have to be worried about cut fruit, but one does if it's a lemon? Is it because lemons are charif? If so, why wouldn't #1 mention charif fruits/vegetables as an exception?

*CYLOR about whether to rely on the information in this document, like any.*

Comment: Consider posting a follow up question there asking him to clarify what he meant. He would probably know best.

Comment: Probably you're right about lemon being charif and he is assuming no one buys sliced lemon in a fruit salad or something like that

Comment: Rabbi Rubanowitz received semicha from Beit Medrosh Gevoha of Lakewood, NJ and later Dayanut. He is Rav of Kol Rina Synagogue in Israel, serves as a judge with Institute for Dayanim in Jerusalem and teaches at New England Institute for Jewish Studies. http://neijs.org/2010/02/10/faculty/

Comment: His bio from the Kol Rina Synagogue in Israel. http://kolrinashul.org/our-rav/

Comment: His bio from Dinonline.org. http://dinonline.org/2010/02/22/rabbi-baruch-rubanowitz/

Comment: He also appears to be affiliated with the Rabbinical Council of Victoria in Australia. https://www.zoominfo.com/p/Baruch-Rubanowitz/260565167

Comment: https://www.rcv.org.au

Comment: The only thing I would point out from your linked article is that he is writing about when one is on the road and traveling. The article is not for normal living at home. There may be lenient views because of the circumstances.

Comment: In the linked article, he is using a specific example of cold, cut fruit salad. He is not at that point discussing vegetables. He is also only talking about when one is on the road traveling. Those vegetables which are also charif, like for example onions, would be treated like lemons. From what I see in his article, in general, it appears reliable. Your final comment, CYLOR, like in all situations is the correct course of action when one has a question about how to act in accordance with halacha personally.

Comment: @SAH And if you have a question about his comment concerning fresh, cut onions purchased while traveling, following what the Shach brings from Shibolei HaLeket, any potential issue with the knife would be nullified after two onions were cut. Nullified in 1/60. It is not talking about someone slicing a single onion for you, but rather purchasing from a bin of raw pre-cut onions with nothing added.

Comment: @YaacovDeane "In the linked article, he is using a specific example of cold, cut fruit salad. He is not at that point discussing vegetables." Then why does he preface it with "Fresh fruits and **vegetables** grown in chutz la’aretz are kosher whether bought whole or cut" (emphasis added)?

Comment: Concept of klal v'prat.

Comment: @YaacovDeane A few things concerned me but this one stands out: "Bread made of kosher ingredients and baked by a gentile may be eaten." Is this also klal v'prat?

Comment: @SAH Bli Neder, after Yom Tov, I'll look at that point in the article. I'm guessing he's talking about pas palter or some unusual commercial baking arrangement. I'll let you know what I see. You need to understand, this Rav is a working Dayan in Yerushalayim. He definitely knows kitchen shailahs like you are concerned about.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Of course he must be extremely knowledgeable; I just wonder why he has written this article in such an apparently misleading way. Someone who doesn't know the difference between pas palter and pas akum could be quite easily and egregiously misled by this, I think

Comment: @SAH The bread paragraph says that you must know that in all the products produced at that bakery no non-kosher ingredients are used. Absent that knowledge, you must assume not kosher. What he's writing is accurate. It's not a problem and not misleading. Again, emphasizing that he is discussing someone who is traveling on the road. It seems to me that this may be the part you are overlooking.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Nonetheless if someone with little knowledge took some of these sentences in isolation as guidelines for his habits, there could be real problems from things like "Bread made of kosher ingredients and baked by a gentile may be eaten" and "Fresh fruits and vegetables grown in chutz la’aretz are kosher whether bought whole or cut." Not sure what justifies putting something so simply that is actually very complicated (unless "klal v'prat" is a very blank check indeed)

Answer (score 4):

As stated from [Din online](https://dinonline.org/2011/03/16/coke-with-lemon/) where Rav Rubanowitz also works, they hold that by some views, lemon is considered a davar charif and so it's usage is different from other cut fruits. They reference the Shach to Yoreh Deah 96:20 discussing lemon juice. The Shach is following what is found in Shibolei HaLeket which appears to say that lemon is in a class of being mildly charif.